# Slider change with sidebar button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my slider change with some button I have in my page with pure javascript.

I try to define a common value between button and slider to make a loop in js  to change the slider, When I push a button but whatever I do it doesn't work at all.

```js
        var i,j;
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName("part");
        var circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
        var s = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
        var test = document.getElementById("el");
        for(j=0;j<x.length;j++)
        {
            x[j].addEventListener("click",function(){
                for(i=0;i<circle.length;i++){
                    let t = circle[i];
                    t.style.display="none";
    
                }
                for(j=0;j<s.length;j++){
                    let m = s[j];
                    m.style.display="none";
                }
                var y=this.firstElementChild;
                y.style.display="block";
    
            });
        }
        function  show(evt,name) {
            document.getElementById(name).style.display="block";
        }
    
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);
    
        function plusSlides(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }
    
    
    
        function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }
        function showSlides(n) {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
            if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        }
```

```css
            *
            {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .main
            {
                width: 60%;
                height: 500px;
                margin:100px auto;
                position: relative;
            }
            .sidebar
            {
                border-left: 2px dashed #434a54;
                width: 30%;
                float: right;
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                right:0;
                height:auto;
            }
    
            .sidebar ul
            {
                margin-left: 32px;
                font-size: 60px;
                color:#ffc732;
    
            }
            ul li{
                width: 100%;
                height: 60px;
                line-height: 60px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                position: relative;
                cursor: pointer;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            li.part:hover span
            {
    
                color:#ffc732;
            }
    
            li.part span{
                width:100px ;
                font-size: 23px;
                color: #775702;;
                display: inline-block;
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                text-align: right;
                font-family:"B Nazanin";
            }
    
    
            ul>li:first-child::before
            {
                content: "";
                width:5px;
                height: 24px;
                background-color:white;
                position: absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:-35px;
                z-index: -1;
            }
            ul>li:last-child::before
            {
                content: "";
                width:5px;
                height: 30px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom:-13px;
                left:-35px;
                background-color: white;
                z-index: -1;
            }
            .circle {
                width: 28px;
                height: 28px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border: 3px solid #ffc732;
                position: absolute;
                top: 19px;
                left: -46px;
                background-color: white;
                z-index: -1;
                display: none;
            }
            .content {
                width: 70%;
                height: auto;
                padding: 50px;
            }
            /***********************slider**************/
            .mySlides
            {display: none}
            .slideshow-container img
            {
                width: 100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            .slideshow-container {
                max-width: 1000px;
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
            }
            .prev, .next {
                cursor: pointer;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                width: auto;
                padding: 16px;
                margin-top: -22px;
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 18px;
                transition: 0.6s ease;
                border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
                user-select: none;
            }
            .next {
                right: 0;
                border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
            }
            .prev:hover, .next:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            }
            .text {
                color: #f2f2f2;
                font-size: 15px;
                padding: 8px 12px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 8px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .dot {
                cursor: pointer;
                height: 15px;
                width: 15px;
                margin: 0 2px;
                background-color: #bbb;
                border-radius: 50%;
                display: inline-block;
                transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
            }
            .active, .dot:hover {
                background-color: #717171;
            }
            .fade {
                -webkit-animation-name: fade;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
                animation-name: fade;
                animation-duration: 1.5s;
            }
            @keyframes fade {
                from {opacity: .4}
                to {opacity: 1}
            }
```

```html
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li class="part" >
                    <button class="circle" style="display: block;!important;"  id="btn1" value="1" onclick="showVal(this.value)"></button>
                    <span >?????? ???</span>
                </li>
                <li class="part">
                    <button class="circle" id="btn2" value="2" onclick="showVal(this.value)" ></button>
                    <span >?????? ???</span>
                </li>
                <li class="part" >
                    <button class="circle" id="btn3" value="3" onclick="showVal(this.value)" ></button>
                    <span >?????? ???</span>
                </li>
                <li class="part" >
                    <button class="circle" id="btn4" value="4" onclick="showVal(this.value)"></button>
                    <span >?????? ?????</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
    
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="e1">
            <h2>
                slider1
            </h2>
            <div class="slideshow-container" id="testslider">
    
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="1%20(1).png" id="slimg1" >
                    <div class="text" >Caption Text</div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="mySlides fade" id="slimg2">
                    <img src="1%20(2).png">
                    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="mySlides fade" id="slimg3">
                    <img src="1%20(3).png" >
                    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
                </div>
    
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    
            </div>
            <br>
    
            <div style="text-align:center">
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="e2">
            <h2>slider2</h2>
            <div class="slideshow-container">
    
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="image2.jpg">
                    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="image2.jpg" >
                    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="mySlides fade">
                    <img src="image2.jpg">
                    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
                </div>
    
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to change the slider when I push a button in my page.

Comment: Check my answer mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a lot of time to debug your code. It just so messy but finally I make it for you. There is a few line you need to change:

JS:

```
for (let i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
  circle[i].onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var partIndex = e.target.value;
    console.log(e.target.value, "click");
    let t = circle[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < circle.length; j++) {
      circle[j].classList.remove("active");
    }
    t.classList.add("active");
    for(let k=0; k<s.length;k++){
      s[k].style.display = 'none';
    }
    changePartHTML(partIndex)
  };
}
    function changePartHTML(partIndex){
 //Do something here
  var targetPart = document.querySelector('#e'+partIndex);
  targetPart.style.display = 'block';
}
```

CSS need to change at:

```
.circle {
                width: 28px;
                height: 28px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border: 3px solid #ffc732;
                position: absolute;
                top: 19px;
                left: -46px;
                background-color: white;
                z-index: 9999;
                display: block;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
.part .active{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Check demo code at: https://codepen.io/tien-bui/pen/BvwKVb

Comment: tnx a lot about the try you do
but do you think you can make the image of the one slider change not the whole slider

Comment: Yes you can. You can see my function changePart(), you just need to change it to showImage with the input partIndex, it will show the right image with the input. But you have 4 part and 3 image. How can it work?

Comment: can you please do this for me it doesn't matter what i do it didnt fix

Comment: just want to confirm, what you want is when user click on part-1, part-2, part-3. It will change the image inside the silder 1. Is it correct?

Comment: What I do for you is: you have 4 part and each part have 1 slider, so when you click on the part-1, part-2, it will change the different slider for you

Comment: Check it again mate: `https://codepen.io/tien-bui/pen/BvwKVb` when you click the button, the slide change